# LOCAL JSON vs External File

Tags: react-native

I found a post on here which suggested how to use a local json file for data in react native. It suggested I use var custom data = {filename}.. However I can't seem to make it work personally... I was wondering if anyone could please help me out. Here is the code

```
const customData = require('../dr.json')

export default class DailyReportListScreen extends React.Component {


  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const params = navigation.state.params || {}
    console.log(params)
    return {
      headerTitle: 'Daily Reports',
      headerRight: (
        <Button title="Log out" onPress={() => 
navigation.navigate('AddDailyReportForm')} color="#a41034" />
      ),
     }   
  }

  state = {
    data = [customData]
  };

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}
    data: [customData]
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({data: this.customData});
  }

   render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
           data={this.state.data}
           keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
           renderItem={({ data }) =>
        <Text>
        {data.data.name}
        </Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    marginTop: 15,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  }
});
```

Here is the json data:

```
{
 "recordcount": 25015,
   "data": [{
    "name": "joe"
    "number": 12
},
{
    "name": bill
    "number": 5
}]
}
```

I am unsure if it is an issue with my flatlist, or if I am extracting the data incorrectly..

Answer (score 0):

You have to export your data:

data.js:

```
export const DATA = {
  'recordcount': 25015,
  'data': [
    {
      'name': 'joe',
      'number': 12,
    },
    {
      'name': 'bill',
      'number': 5,
    }
  ]
}
```

and import it properly like so:

```
import { DATA } from '../path/to/local/file/data.js'

export default class DailyReportListScreen extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(DATA)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried adding that      export const DATA = and got the error   "Expected a JSON object, array or literal"

Comment: And there were one useless comma